# Reassign a variable a value in a foreach/for loop, and then use that value outside of the loop?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6

I want to use and display the value of c(which I assigned a variable named test2 to) used in the foreach loop, but the variable shows null value when used outside of the foreach loop. How can I access the value of test2 or c? I tried to append the value of c/test2 to a list at one point, but could not manage to display the value of that list as a string.

```
class encryptionFunctionClass
{

    List<string> textConvertedToArray = new List<string>();
    List<string> charToMessageBox = new List<string>();
    string inputText;
    string inputTextToChar;
    char test1; // Poor Naming Conventions Ik.
    char test2; // Poor Naming Conventions Ik.
    bool isReturn = false;
    bool isNotReturn = true;
    int test3;
    char c;

    public int caesarEncryptText(string inputText, int encryptionNumberShift)
    {
        textConvertedToArray.Add(inputText);
        foreach (char c in inputText.ToString().ToCharArray())
        {
            int i = 0;
            char test2 = c;
            test1 = test2;
            if ((char)c + encryptionNumberShift >= 24)
            {
                isReturn = true;

                test2 = c;
                charToMessageBox.Add(c.ToString());

            }
            else
            {
                isNotReturn = true;
                test2 = c;
                charToMessageBox.Add(c.ToString());
            }

        }
           while(true)

           MessageBox.Show(test2.ToString());

            if(isReturn == true)
            {
                return (char)c - (int)26;
            }
            else
            {
                if(isNotReturn == true)
                {

                    return (char) + (int)24;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# follows block scoping. Same named variable `c` and `test2` are also present as member variables of your class. Using the same named variables inside your method creates new variable altogether and your member variables declared at class level get suppressed. So any change made to `c` and `test2`variables inside `caesarEncryptText` method will have no impact on member variables which are defined at class level.

```
class encryptionFunctionClass
{
    char test2; // Poor Naming Conventions Ik.
    char c;

    public int caesarEncryptText(string inputText, int encryptionNumberShift)
    {
        textConvertedToArray.Add(inputText);
        foreach (char c in inputText.ToString().ToCharArray())
        {
            //other code
            //this test2 variable is NOT your member variable
            char test2 = c;
            //remaining code
        }
     }
}
```

To actually change the member variables instead you have two ways:

1. Do not declare `test2` variable locally inside your method. Then if you change `test2` inside your method, it will change your member variable. This is what you should ideally be doing. **Having same named variables at class level and at method level is dirty code**.
2. Access the member variable using `this` keyword inside your method if you want to change the member variable instead as shown below:

   ```
   foreach (char c in inputText.ToString().ToCharArray())
   {
       //other code
       //using this keyword will modify your member variable

       this.test2 = c;

       //remaining code
   }
   ```

Comment: @ColtonSkees use `this` keyword to access fields of a class.

Comment: Because you never assigned a value to `c`

Comment: @ColtonSkees, you have a `foreach` variable called `c`. That `c` variable will be the characters of the inputtext for each iteration step. You also have field called `c` in your `caesarEncryptText` you have not for once touched that `c` variable defined as a field

Answer (score 0):

Local variables declared in `public int caesarEncryptText(string inputText, int encryptionNumberShift)` hides (makes them inaccessible unless accessed with `this` keyword) class fields with the same name.

```
private string inputText; //←Hidden by the caesarEncryptText Method's variable `inputText`
private string inputTextToChar;
private char test1; // Poor Naming Conventions Ik.
private char test2; //←Hidden by the caesarEncryptText Method's foreach loop
private bool isReturn = false;
private bool isNotReturn = true;
private int test3;
private char c; //←Hidden by the caesarEncryptText Method's foreach loop
```

What you are after maybe something like this:

```
public class EncryptionFunctionClass {

    private char c;　//Default value of '\0'    

    public char ShadowingExample(string inputText, int encryptionNumberShift) {
    foreach (var c in inputText) {
        //Play with `c` here will not affect private char c declared above.
        var anotherChar = (char)(c + 24);//Etc..
    }
    return c;←Still '\0'!!!!
} 

    public string CaesarEncryptText(string inputText, int encryptionNumberShift) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var c in inputText) { sb.Append((char)(c + encryptionNumberShift)); }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```